# Is it possible to git grep only through the modifications added by a particular commit?

Tags: git, grep

Suppose I commit 20 files, which may contain a string like `I18n.t`. Is it possible to find all these lines, but only in the files that were modified by that commit? If I do something like:

```
git grep I18n.t commit_sha
```

it finds me lines that are in other files as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `git show`:

```
git show commit_sha | grep I18n.t
```